# I dont know 0xAA55 get in byte array (size 2)

Tags: java, tcp, byte, protocols

I developing TCP Server Program but I stucked this Server's Protocol
the header is fixed by 0xAA55, header size is 2 Byte
this is the problem I dont know fill in 0xAA55 to byte array

byte[] tmp = new byte[2];
tmp = 0xAA55;

this is not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap `tmp` with a `ByteBuffer` and then use [`ByteBuffer.putShort(short)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putShort-short-) like

```
byte[] tmp = new byte[2];
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(tmp);
bb.putShort((short) 0xAA55);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmp));
```